# Spring Datasource bean configuration with .properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Until now I'v worked with simple spring project and my Datasource bean was configured through the xml file, now I am using the Spring Boot, and there isnt an xml file.

The question is - where do i configure the Datasource bean now? at the application.properties file? (with `spring.datasource.driver-class-name
spring.datasource.url` for example) or somewhere else?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in Spring boot datasource configuration happen on application.properties file ideally. 
[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)  is the reference.

Comment: So it means that i don't need to create a bean, instead i am passing it to the application.properties and thats it?
Because I am using a JdbcTamplate bean, and I am setting the datasource inside it, so how do i pass the datasource to the JdbcTamplate bean now?

Comment: Stil you should be able to autowire JdbcTemplate as  before. Spring boot will take care of datasource bean initialization.